# How can i store Built-in Camera images in my application gallery?

Tags: android, gallery

How can i store Built-in Camera images in my application gallery?

I have a gallery in my application, and i want to store image taken from build in camera in to my gallery.

Is it possible to store image to our own gallery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, get the images from where Built in camera will store images.from that path you can get images into your gallery app.general path is sdcard/DCIM/camera

Comment: Is there is any other way to store images directly to application gallery with out storing in Phone Gallery??

Comment: Built in camera app has that location as default.In camera setting u can change it.google it.